# New column with summing up constant value on preceding value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement in SQL Server to get a new column from my table where the new column is obtained by summing up constant value i.e. 500 from the available column.

I have attached sample data here, I need to get column RequiredNewColumn.

Here column RequiredNewColumn = column Revenue for the first row
after that add 500 to the preceding value of column RequiredNewColumn.

DDL here

```
SELECT '1/1/2019' AS Ddate,
       '5000' AS Revenue
INTO #tempA UNION
SELECT '1/2/2019',
       '4000'
UNION
SELECT '1/3/2019',
       '3000'
UNION
SELECT '1/4/2019',
       '2000'
UNION
SELECT '1/5/2019',
       '6000'
UNION
SELECT '1/6/2019',
       '4000'
UNION
SELECT '1/7/2019',
       '2000'
UNION
SELECT '1/8/2019',
       '3000'
UNION
SELECT '1/9/2019',
       '6000'
UNION
SELECT '1/10/2019',
       '5000'



SELECT *
FROM #tempA
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Can you also please provide the DDL scripts and the Insert scripts so its easier to work on the required sql

Comment: Expected output please ?

Comment: @xXx The expected output is the Required New Column in the snapshot above.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph I have added the DDL sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3ff58/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (DateCol Date, Revenue int)
INSERT INTO MyTable (DateCol,Revenue) VALUES ('1/1/2019',5000),
                     ('1/2/2019',4000),('1/3/2019',3000),
                     ('1/4/2019',2000),('1/5/2019',6000)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    DateCol, Revenue,
    ((ROW_NUMBER() over (order by DateCol)-1)*500)+5000 AS RequiredNewColumn 
FROM MyTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3ff58/1/0)**:

```
|    DateCol | Revenue | RequiredNewColumn |
|------------|---------|-------------------|
| 2019-01-01 |    5000 |              5000 |
| 2019-01-02 |    4000 |              5500 |
| 2019-01-03 |    3000 |              6000 |
| 2019-01-04 |    2000 |              6500 |
| 2019-01-05 |    6000 |              7000 |
```